# Object Orientated Programming in java || not sure why my list customer not printing a list of customers

Tags: java, object

```
public class CustomerManager {
    private customer[] list;
    private int maxcustomer;
    private int numcustomer;

    public CustomerManager(int size){
        maxcustomer = size;
        numcustomer = 0;
        list = new customer[size];
    }

    //add customer
    public boolean addcustomer(String Address, String Name){
        customer x = new customer(Address, Name);
        if(numcustomer < maxcustomer){
            list[numcustomer] = x;

            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

1. The list customer method is not listing customers
2. I assume its because data isn't properly being passed through to the managers but not exactly sure where I went wrong

   ```
   public String listcustomer(){
       String s = " ";
       int i;
       for(i = 0; i < numcustomer; i++){
           s += list[i].getname();list[i].getaddress();
       }
       return s;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: When you add a customer you need to increase 'numcustomer'. For example, `list[numcustomer] = x; numcustomer++;` or even `list[numcustomer++] = x`

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.

Couple things - when writing java 
classes should start with Capital letter, while variables and functions with small letter.

Second when adding new customer you have to increase counter

```
public boolean addcustomer(String address, String name){
    Customer x = new Customer(address, name);
    if(numcustomer < maxcustomer){
        list[numcustomer] = x;
        numcustomer++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But instead of it I would recommend storing customers in Collection like List or [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) ( to prevent duplicates ).Then you won't have to worry about increasing counter, as you will have it built in.

```
private Set<Customer> customers;

public CustomerManager(int size){
    maxcustomer = size;
    customers = new HashSet();
}

public boolean addcustomer(String address, String name){
    Customer newCustomer = new Customer(address, name);
    if(customers.size() < maxcustomer){
        customers.add(newCustomer)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To ensure Set won't store duplicates, you have to properly implement hashCode and equals [more info](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts)